# Redirection to action asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have the action (analyser) and I want to redirect to other actions passing the argument of a list of float, but always the list is empty:

- In the action Analyser, I fill the list(sfr) of floats and I pass it like an argument to the actions(_two or _three or.... _others) but the list become empty.

  ```
  // GET: /Historique/
  [HttpGet] 
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
       return View();
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult _two(IList<float> sf)
  {
       return View(sf);
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult _three(IList<float> sf)
  { 
       return View(sf);
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult _four(IList<float> sf)
  {
       return View(sf);
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult _five(IList<float> sf)
  {  
       return View(sf);
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult _six(IList<float> sf)
  {
       return View(sf);
  }
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult _others(IList<float> sf)
  {
       return View(sf);
  }
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Analyser(FormCollection collection)
  {
        IList<float> sfr = new List<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Global.seg.Count; i++)
        {
             if (collection.AllKeys.Contains(i.ToString())) {
                 foreach (Point e in Global.seg[i]._pointsListe)
                 {
                      sfr.Add(e._latitude);
                      sfr.Add(e._longitude);
                  }
              }
         }

         if (sfr.Count == 4) return RedirectToAction("_two", new { sf = sfr });
         if (sfr.Count == 6) return RedirectToAction("_two", new { sf = sfr });
         if (sfr.Count == 8) return RedirectToAction("_four", new { sf = sfr });
         if (sfr.Count == 10) return RedirectToAction("_five", new { sf = sfr });
         if (sfr.Count == 12) return RedirectToAction("_six", new { sf = sfr });
         else return RedirectToAction("_others",sfr);
           }
      }
  }
  ```

So what is the matter and how can I correct it?

Comment: I think you need to give some more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: debug and check if sfr is not null when you redirect

Comment: i try to pass a list of float in argument to an other action so i fill it and i redirect to the new action but the list become empty

Comment: I find finally the solution : declar a public static list of float (sf), and before the redirection sf=sfr. the other actions must be without argument and i did inside it return View(sf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Analyser(FormCollection collection)
{
    IList<float> sfr = new List<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Global.seg.Count; i++)
    {
        if (collection.AllKeys.Contains(i.ToString())) 
        {
            foreach (Point e in Global.seg[i]._pointsListe)
            {
                sfr.Add(e._latitude);
                sfr.Add(e._longitude);
            }
        }
    }

    var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
    for (int i = 0; i < sfr.Count; i++)
    {
        rvd[string.Format("sf[{0}]", i)] = sfr[i];
    }

    if (sfr.Count == 4) return RedirectToAction("_two", rvd);
    if (sfr.Count == 6) return RedirectToAction("_two", rvd);
    if (sfr.Count == 8) return RedirectToAction("_four", rvd);
    if (sfr.Count == 10) return RedirectToAction("_five", rvd);
    if (sfr.Count == 12) return RedirectToAction("_six", rvd);
    else return RedirectToAction("_others", rvd);
}
```